# ValueError: time data '04/19/19 08:46' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> ```
> Order Date
> ```

0   04/19/19 08:46
2   04/07/19 22:30
3   04/12/19 14:38
4   04/12/19 14:38
5   04/30/19 09:27

This is my column in DataFrame and the type of the column is 'object'

```
df.dtypes
```

Order Date          object

I am trying to convert it to date time with the bellow code but getting error.

```
df['Order Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

I have tried multiple options but still getting error

ValueError: time data '04/19/19 08:46' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match)

Please help me with this!

Comment: @ChrisCharley Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to add format, pandas recognize it automatically:

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])
```

or use datetime instead:

```
import datetime

df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'))
```

if error is inevitable, or can't locate it, or don't know how to proceed, do this:

```
#example df with non datetime value
    Order Date
0   04/19/19 08:46
1   04/07/19 22:30
2   random text

df['Order Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], errors='coerce')

df 
    Order Date      Order Date2
0   04/19/19 08:46  2019-04-19 08:46:00
1   04/07/19 22:30  2019-04-07 22:30:00
2   random text     NaT

df.loc[df['Order Date2'].isna()] #isolate the row where error exist
    Order Date  Order Date2
2   random text NaT
```

Comment: I am still having this error: ParserError: Unknown string format: Order Date

Comment: I updated my answer, isolate the row with error (use ```errors='coerce'```) and let me know what hapened

Comment: after adding "errors='coerce'" it is finally working. Could you please explain what is errors='coerce'

Comment: if you put errors='coerce', then invalid datetime will be set as None automatically and no error will be raised, without it, pandas will raise error when it can't convert string to datetime

Comment: check the reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Order Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

EDIT to reflect your comment:

Have you tried to do this?

```
df['Order Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])
```

Try this to print dates that dont fit the format

```
from datetime import datetime
for date_str in df["Order Date"]:
    try:
        a = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
    except ValueError:
        print(date_str)
```

Comment: Hi @bitflip, I am still having an error:  ValueError: time data 'Order Date' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M' (match)

Comment: Can you share your dataframe with us? Maybe you have multiple formats in your Column? If I use `from datetime import datetime 

datetime.strptime("04/19/19 08:46", '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')` I can achieve the desired result.

Comment: please check this, it doesn't have same columns https://ibb.co/s5tpH72

Comment: I've made a suggestion to identify different date formats in my post (for easier code highlighting)

Comment: So basically I have to apply that with the df column right?

Comment: I would try to identify cells that dont fit your/any datetime format first. Maybe its just some random string anywhere in your column... Then you can decide what to do with those values and either replace or ignore them.